# GPG decrypt returns empty file

Tags: gpg

Im decrypting a file sent by a client using gpg. The file is Obviusly encrypted, and theoretically, using my public key.

I have installed both his public key and my private key.

So, im running:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpg --output a.log  --decrypt --passphrase=mypassphrase --batch /usr/local/log/Banesco11052015.TXT.pgp
```

*gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID B61CC86B, created 2014-11-06
      "Company SRL "
gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected*

But a.log is empty.

I also tried as well:

```
echo mypassphrase | gpg  --output a.log --passphrase-fd 0 /usr/local/log/Banesco11052015.TXT.pgp
```

The encrypted file has content, but is it possible though it has encrypted content, the file is actually empty on decryption?

Am I running the decrypt command wrongly? Maybe there is a problem with my keys?

Thanks in advance!

E.

Comment: What is the exit status of the `gpg` command? (Put `echo $? >&2` after the `/usr/local/bin/gpg …` line to display it.)

Comment: Does not like that:
/usr/local/bin/gpg echo $? >&2 --output a.log  --decrypt --passphrase=mypassphrase --batch /usr/local/log/Banesco11052015.TXT.pgp
usage: gpg [options] [filename]

Comment: Not *on* the line with the `gpg` command. On the next line.

Comment: Oh, hehe... Its "0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, as @PSkocik, the file was empty.

Apparently, those 900 bytes on it were header information regarding the encryption.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

`gpg` seems to depend on a particular argument ordering (unfortunately not all command-line utilities allow as unrestricted argument ordering as possible) .

It should work if you follow the pattern from the man page:

```
gpg [--homedir dir] [--options file] [options] command [args]
```

In your case:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpg --output a.log --passphrase=mypassphrase  --decrypt  /usr/local/log/Banesco11052015.TXT.pgp
```

I would start with the simplest

```
gpg --decrypt /usr/local/log/Banesco11052015.TXT.pgp
```

and, if it works, add `--passphrase` and `--output` later:

Comment: I tried that: It makes me input the passphrase, and then nothing happens after "gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected" just like the other one. It should print the decrypted text, right? Then, same issue here

Comment: If it the command returns zero (=ran sucessfully), the message was simply empty.

Comment: Apparently it did run succesfully. But the encrypted file has some bytes on it! About 844 bytes. Is it possible that its size is 844 bytes but decrypted, its zero?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.